angular fire 18.01 null inject error when initiliazing component
Since yesterday night that I have been dealing with this error:
   main.ts:5 ERROR NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options!
    at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:1659:27)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3105:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3105:33)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:1106:40)
    at ɵɵinject (core.mjs:1112:42)
    at Object.AngularFireDatabase_Factory [as factory] (angular-fire-compat-database.mjs:376:46)
    at core.mjs:3233:47
    at runInInjectorProfilerContext (core.mjs:871:9)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:3232:21)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3095:33)

I got this when I init my test component which I want to use to ping firestore to ensure that my webview is communicating with the backend.
this is my module:
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

    import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
    import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
    import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';

    import { environment } from '../environments/environment';



     @NgModule({
      declarations: [],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
        AngularFireAuthModule,
        AngularFireDatabaseModule

      ],
    })
export class AppModule { }

I am currently using angular 18.0 and angulare fire 18.01`
this is my super simple component for testing firestore, and the template only contains a button to call insertData()
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
     export class FirebaseService {
      constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

      insertData(data: any) {
        return this.db.list('/items').push(data);
      }
    }

when I try to initialize my component a blank page is displayed without error in the angular cli, but the errors where displayed in the console

could you share github repo for debugging?

Any chance you generated a fresh Angular 18 standalone app and manually added an app.module.ts? In this case it would be ignored by Angular. You should configure your app in app.config.ts instead.

yep, i generated the app with the cli and added the module.ts later manually, i will try to follow this path thank you sir

After generating a fresh Angular v18+ standalone app, don't manually add an app.module.ts! It will not have any effect. This is the reason why you are experiencing this error. Instead, you should do the configuration in the app.config.ts. Also you should use provider functions instead of the modules, if possible:
import { provideFirebaseApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp({ ... })),
  ],
}

See the Angular Fire docs.

i did the configuration in the app.config file, but i still got the same error, if you want i can share my repo with you, thanks for the help anyway

@muhamadveroforte a link to the repo would be helpful

https://github.com/emilianoPiz/evara-frontend here you go mister

@muhamadveroforte in the repository there are no environments. Do you have them locally?

yes of course but i won't push environmets to github.
apiKey: "",
authDomain: "",
projectId: "",
storageBucket: "",
messagingSenderId: ",
appId: "",
measurementId: ""
This is how it looks without the properties

You can fix this issue, by changing the way you import Firestore. It should be imported from 'firebase/firestore' and then using this, we can use the Firebase functions collection or addDoc to perform DB operations.
Cloud Firestore Docs Reference 1
AngularFire
firebase.service.ts
import { Injectable, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Firestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { collection, addDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirebaseService {
  private firestore = inject(Firestore);
  constructor() { }

  insertData(data: any) {
    // get a reference to the user-profile collection
    const itemsCollection = collection(this.firestore, 'items');
    
    // get documents (data) from the collection using collectionData
    return addDoc(itemsCollection, data);
  }
}

shop.component.ts
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseService } from '../../services/firebase.service';
import { Firestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { addDoc, collection } from 'firebase/firestore';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shop',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './shop.component.html',
  styleUrl: './shop.component.scss'
})
export class ShopComponent {
  private firestore = inject(Firestore);
  data = { message: 'Hello, Firebase!' };
  insertData() {
    const itemsCollection = collection(this.firestore, 'items');
    addDoc(itemsCollection, this.data).then(() => {
      console.log('Data inserted successfully');
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error('Error inserting data', error);
    });
  }
}

Github Fork

thank you sooo much, you saved my day! i'm  sorry i can't upvote but i merged your commit directly into main! you was great!

i have done it my friend!

add     { provide: FIREBASE_OPTIONS, useValue: environment.firebase } in the providor array in app.config.ts  file.
   import { FIREBASE_OPTIONS } from '@angular/fire/compat';
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    provideIonicAngular(),
    provideRouter(routes, withPreloading(PreloadAllModules)),
    provideHttpClient(),
    importProvidersFrom(IonicModule.forRoot()),
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    { provide: FIREBASE_OPTIONS, useValue: environment.firebase },
  ],
});

